# Connection issues on OSX via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

I'm trying to write a python app (python 3.5 with pyCharm IDE) that put multiple queries and do math etc... It needs to run on both mac and windows. On windows side because of pymssql won't work i tried pyodbc which worked flawlessly (it's the opposite on mac side). But on the mac side whenever i try to connect with this code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServerIp;DATABASE=myDatabaseName;UID=myUserName;PWD=myPassword')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

it gives the error of: `pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'odbc.ini' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Normally i can connect MS SQL from excel or any other query software on mac. I'm using Actual SQL Server driver on system wide.

So please guide me to fix this problem either using Actual SQL Server drivers (which is paid version) or properly configure python or unixodbc (not sure which is the problem). Thank you and regards

PS: I installed both pyodbc, unixodbc and freetds via pip as i followed documentation

Update1:

```
 $ cat $(odbc_config --odbcinstini)
[ODBC]
DEBUG=1
TraceFile=/home/ftp/sqltrace.log
Trace=Yes

[FreeTDS]
Description=MSSQL Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
$ odbc_config --ulen
-DSIZEOF_SQLULEN=8
$ odbc_config --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/lib -lodbc
$ odbc_config --prefix
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1
$ odbc_config --odbcinstini
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini
$ odbc_config --odbcini
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbc.ini
$ odbc_config --version
2.3.2
```

Comment: Could you please update your question adding the output of the following commands? (1) `odbc_config --version` (2) `odbc_config --odbcini` (3) `odbc_config --odbcinstini` (4) `odbc_config --prefix` (5) `odbc_config --libs` (6) `odbc_config --ulen` (7) `cat $(odbc_config --odbcinstini)`

Comment: OK. I'd suggest to create a DSN in odic.ini and test the ODBC layer - on its own - first with `isql <DSN> <USER> <PASSWORD>`. If this is ok, then my second test would be to connect using pyodbc using the same DSN.

Comment: i re-installed with  brew install freetds --with-unixodbc command and that did the trick for me. Before that i tried your suggestion but it still gave me the same error. By the way the missing files are created when i did use the code above. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uninstalling and installing again with this command fixed the issue:

```
brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

Comment: uninstall the pyodbc library first and then install that library again? or do you mean uninstall unixodbc first?